# JSON Python get field as array

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

This is my response to a get request for some json goodness. 
I'm getting this in Python, everything works up to here. 
I've been searching for json documentation and reading quite a bit but can't seam to find my answer.

How would I get all the email addresses?

```
{u'-InFSLzYdyg-OcTosYYs': {u'email': u'hello@gmail.com', u'time': 1360707022892}, u'-    InFYJya4K6tZa8YSzme': {u'email': u'me@gmail.com', u'time': 1360708587511}}
```

What I'd want is a list like so:

```
email = ['hello@gmail.com', 'me@gmail.com']
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Like wRAR said, once you have it as a python `dict`, it should be as simple as:

```
[x['email'] for x in l.itervalues()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're converted you JSON string to a python dict (see [loads())](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
>>> from json import loads
>>> myJSON = loads(somejsonstring)
>>> emails = [a[x]['email'] for x in a]
>>> emails
['hello@gmail.com', 'me@gmail.com']
```

Or even better, use `itervalues()` as Luke mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `json.loads` and process the resulting `dict` as usual. There is nothing JSON-specific here.